# How can I access the python documentation for the thing at cursor?

Tags: spacemacs, python

```python
with open("foo.txt", mode="create") as f:
    print(file, text[0:300], file=f)
```

`ValueError: invalid mode: 'create'`

Now pointint the cursor on =open=, followed by hitting `,` `h` offers:

- **helm-pydoc** which asks to select one of the imported modules
- **lsp-describe-thing-at-point** which displays amongst others `..mode:OpenTextMode =...`
- **pylookup-lookup** which offers a large list where the word open appears

None does help me understand the problem, nor lead to the documentation of **mode**

How can I access the python documentation for the thing at point?

Comment: Lsp module uses ```dash``` to show documentation; should be enabled/installed  by default, but you need to add the package ```dash-docs``` to your configuration and download the documentation (Python 3, Numpy, Scipy, etc).

Comment: Try to use `elpy`.

Answer (score 1):

One good solution that works here is by using simply `pydoc` (not `helm-pydoc`). Put your cursor somewhere on `open` and do `M-x pydoc-at-point-no-jedi`. Of course, you can bind some shortcut for it also.

Comment: The command should be available after you synced (git pull) Spacemacs, and restarted it.